# community user unable to edit tasks assigned to them

Tags: sharing, tasks, permission-sets, lightning-community, community-builder

I have a use case where I have to assign tasks to customer community users and I want them to see those tasks in community and mark them complete once they complete the task. Btw I am using 'Customer Service' Community template. I dragged 'record list' component in the builder and chose the 'task' object and applied the filter 'My tasks'. Now I have tried two things here:

Note: I am acting here as community user and the tasks are assigned to me.

1. Tasks are assigned to the community user on 'CASE' level. By default the OWD for tasks and case is set to private and I can't change that. Hence, when community user clicks the task in the community, it gives the following error

[image]

2. Second thing I tried was assigning tasks to community user on the 'ACCOUNT' with which the community user is associated with. Then when I logged in as community user, I can see account where the tasks have been assigned to the community user. I clicked the account, then to related list, then I can see tasks. I clicked one of the tasks and hit the 'Mark Complete' button. I got the error 'You no longer have permission to change tasks.'

[image]

By default the OWD for account is set to private and for contact is 'Controlled by parent'

Please help me in finding a solution to this. All I want is for a community user to be able to see tasks assigned to him and mark them complete.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean when you describe a Task as assigned "on the Case level" or "on the Account level"? What is the value of the `OwnerId` field for these Tasks?

Comment: That means task object is created as a related list on Case object and Account Object. Also, I am unable to locate OwnerId field on task.

Comment: Tasks are read-only for Customer Community user license, see the [Communities User Licenses help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for sharing this. How about if I create a custom object 'Checklist' that would be substitute for tasks with fields like, subject, due date, priority, status e.t.c and display that in community? Would the customer community license be able to edit those records and basically change the status field from Pending to Completed?